# How to convert this code into a function?

Tags: flutter, dart

This code does a search in a list and returns the item. Depending on the word, using switch case the code becomes longer.

List data = [{"Label": "teXt VariablE sizE", "Value": 1385},{"Label": "Name variable Test", "Value": 1386},{"Label": "sizE Variable sizE", "Value": 1387},{"Label": "sizE Item Size", "Value": 1388}];

```
                    List match = [];

                    String text = "variable size text";

                    var split = text.toString().split(' ');

                    switch (split.length) {
                      case 1:
                        List<dynamic> list1 = data
                            .where((oldValue) => (oldValue['Label']
                                .toString()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .contains(text.toUpperCase())))
                            .toList();

                        match = list1;

                        break;

                      case 2:
                        String one = split[0];
                        String two = split[1];

                        List<dynamic> list1 = data
                            .where((oldValue) => (oldValue['Label']
                                .toString()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .contains(one.toUpperCase())))
                            .toList();
                        List<dynamic> list2 = list1
                            .where((oldValue) => (oldValue['Label']
                                .toString()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .contains(two.toUpperCase())))
                            .toList();

                        match = list2;

                        break;

                      case 3:
                        String one = split[0];
                        String two = split[1];
                        String three = split[2];

                        List<dynamic> list1 = data
                            .where((oldValue) => (oldValue['Label']
                                .toString()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .contains(one.toUpperCase())))
                            .toList();
                        List<dynamic> list2 = list1
                            .where((oldValue) => (oldValue['Label']
                                .toString()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .contains(two.toUpperCase())))
                            .toList();
                        List<dynamic> list3 = list2
                            .where((oldValue) => (oldValue['Label']
                                .toString()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .contains(three.toUpperCase())))
                            .toList();
                        match = list3;
                        break;

                      case 4:
                        break;

                      case 5:
                        break;

                      case 6:
                        break;

                      case 7:
                        break;

                      case 8:
                        break;

                      case 9:
                        break;

                      case 10:
                        break;
                    }

                    print(match);
```

//return search result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felipe your code is hard to read and not going to say bad but not the best way to achieve what you want
I'm going to write an what we can say an enhanced version to achieve that

simply the way will be by sorting the two strings and compare their values

first, let's split the string by word like you did in your question

```
     List<String> splittedText = text.split(" ");
```

now we sort it

```
     splittedText.sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));
     //before sorting
     [variable, size, text]
     //after sorting
     [size, text, variable]
```

now we just loop the list of data to check evrey string and compare it to our text string.

```
     //Same as splittedText but for our data list
     List<String> listOfStringValue =[];

     //looping evrey index in the list
     data.forEach((data){
     //clearing the list to be ready for the new string
                listOfStringValue =[];

                // same logic before in text.split(" "); and the sort
                listOfStringValue = data["Label"].split(" ");
                listOfStringValue.sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));
                      //compare the text in the data to our text if it's the same add it to match list
                      if(listOfStringValue.toString().toLowerCase() == splittedText.toString().toLowerCase()){
                        match.add(data);
                      }
                    });
```

here is the full code as a function

```
void main() {
               List<Map<String,dynamic>> data = [{"Label": "teXt sizE VariablE", "Value": 1385},{"Label": "teXt VariablE sizE", "Value": 1385},{"Label": "Name variable Test", "Value": 1386},{"Label": "sizE Variable sizE", "Value": 1387},{"Label": "sizE Item Size", "Value": 1388}];

               String text = "variable size text";

               print(findTheText(data,text));

}

  
List findTheText(List<Map<String,dynamic>> data,String text){
    
               List match = [];
               List<String> listOfStringValue =[];
               List<String> splittedText = text.split(" ");
               splittedText.sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));
               data.forEach((data){
                      listOfStringValue.clear();
                      listOfStringValue = data["Label"].split(" ");
                      listOfStringValue.sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));
                         
                      if(listOfStringValue.toString().toLowerCase() == splittedText.toString().toLowerCase()){
                        match.add(data);
                      }
                    });
    return match;
  }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! but, I need to search even when the words have different length.  ex =>  String text = "variable size";   String text = "variable size test2"; and the function compares each order with the list and return the corresponding items

Comment: The logic will be the same sort them, compare the shortest length list (of string) with the other one. it will compare the similar words only..(like if your text is 5 words just compare it to the first 5 words of the data strings)

Comment: Ok! but I need to count the splits, so in the code above I used the switch case of the word split length.

Comment: can you explain in 1 2 3 what exactly you want from the code to do, so i can edit the code based on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
List filter(List data, String text) {
  
  List match = [];
  for (var m in text.toString().split(' ')) {
              match.addAll(
                data.where((oldValue) => oldValue['Label']
                                .toString()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .contains(m.toUpperCase())));

  }
                           return match;
  
}


void main() {
  
  String text = "variable size text";
  //text = "abc";
  List data = [{"Label": "abc", "Value": 1385}, {"Label": "teXt VariablE sizE", "Value": 1385},{"Label": "Name variable Test", "Value": 1386},{"Label": "sizE Variable sizE", "Value": 1387},{"Label": "sizE Item Size", "Value": 1388}];
  print(filter(data, text));
  
}
```